# Convert existing SMALLINT data to INTEGER?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in Postgres with ~ 1M rows.  One column in this table stores SMALLINT data.  Now I need to store numbers in this column that are larger than I anticipated.  How can I convert this existing column from SMALLINT to INTEGER?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to change column data type from `smallint` to `integer`:

```
alter table T alter C type integer
```

T and C are table and column name respectively.

> SET DATA TYPE
>
> This form changes the type of a column of a table. Indexes and simple table constraints 
>   involving the column will be automatically converted to use the new column type by 
>   reparsing the originally supplied expression. The optional COLLATE clause specifies a
>   collation for the new column; if omitted, the collation is the default for the new column
>   type. The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column value from the
>   old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as an assignment cast from old data
>   type to new. A USING clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast
>   from old to new type.

Please see [ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-altertable.html) documentation.

Answer (score 7):

As Ondrej says, you can use `ALTER TABLE .. ALTER COLUMN ... TYPE INTEGER`.

However, this will trigger a full table re-write, locking the table against all concurrent writing *or reading* for the duration. This can be time consuming for large tables.

If you need to avoid that, you can make the change in stages.

- `BEGIN`, add a new integer column and `COMMIT`.
- `BEGIN` a transaction and `LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE` to block concurrent inserts.
- `UPDATE` the table, copying the `smallint` data to the `integer` column.
- Now drop the `smallint` column, rename the `integer` column to the `smallint`'s name, and `COMMIT`.

You can even avoid the `LOCK TABLE` and allow concurrent writes if you're willing to write a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger that copies the value from the `smallint` column to the `integer` column on any `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. You need to add this trigger within the same transaction you create the new integer column in so you catch rows added concurrently with your big `UPDATE`. To further reduce the impact of the change on your application you can update the rows in small batches in individual transactions, so you avoid long row-level locks.

I wrote more about this [in this prior dba.SE answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27156/7788).